# React admin with ra-data-hasura provider don't populate variables of the mutation

Tags: react-admin

I'm testing `react-admin(^3.19.10)` with `ra-data-hasura(^0.4.0)`, `graphql(^16.3.0)` and `@apollo/client(^3.5.10)`. Trying to test simple mutation for creating of the posts resource. Getting an error that there is unexpected `null` value for the `String` type. So I figured out that variables of the mutation don't populate by the text input values. Maybe someone have any ideas why that happens.
[image]

Comment: Hi - I have the same error. Did you find the issue by any chance? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this bug is now fixed in version 0.4.1, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/hasura/ra-data-hasura/issues/85). I upgraded to `"ra-data-hasura": "^0.4.1"` and the issue resolved for me.